# Java Automated Test (Out of Bounds Exception)

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, automated-tests

I was writing automated tests and all of them was working good until I tried to enter 14 different examples. After that, it gave `OutOfBoundsException` and stopped running. 
I think it is because I gave too much input and the example array does not have that much size.

Is my assumption correct? How can I change it?

This is the `.feature` code

```
@Smoke  @+ALL  @myidentifier
Scenario Outline: blabla
    When I open blabla
    When I click blabla
    Then I should see blabla
    When I click <buttonName> in  blabla
etc etc etc etc
```

Examples:

```
    |index||buttonName| 
    |1| |bla| 
    |2| |blabla| 
    |3| |blablabla| 
    |4| |blablablabla| 
    |5| |blaa| 
    |6| |bla|
    |7| |input|
    |8| |inputbla|
#   |9| |inputblabla|
```

Comment: show some useful part of your code

Comment: You need to be careful in your code about referencing an array item by index - it sounds like your index variable has trying to find an item which doesn't exist in the array.

Comment: I updated the code part